# Rumors spreading about me leaving my current job

Tags: professionalism

I was approached by former colleagues to join a different company. Few people from this company were former employees of my current company, and they still maintain friendship with the people I work with.

I was offered a position in this new company, and I rejected it at first, however they countered couple of times, and I finally accepted their offer.

The problem is, during this period rumors has started between the lower rank employees at my current work place that I'm leaving even before I accepted offer; it makes me uncomfortable because I have not told my team or, more importantly, current boss yet. I would hate to know that this information gets to my boss before I am able to have a conversation with him. While I am sure there was no ill intent, I know that these rumors were started by a member of the new company who was a former co-worker. This person is a lower rank employee who is going to be working in my group, and probably under me.

Should I email the new company and call her out? or leave it as is?I will officially be resigning tomorrow, and I don't want create any tension in the new work place, but I don't want to passive either!

Answer (score 8):

First, what's done is done. Don't sweat it. Stuff like this happens frequently. At the point when you come to officially tell your boss that you are resigning, say something like "By the way, I'm sorry if this got to you through the rumour mill before I could talk to you, I didn't intend that to happen.". They probably don't care that much.

Second, if you are sure you know who let the cat out of the bag, then have a quiet word and just explain how spreading the rumour hurt you, but make it clear there are no hard feelings. Do this before you join the company so that if you end up being her boss it isn't a boss thing.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I email the new company and call her out?

Short answer: **No**

> I will officially be resigning tomorrow, and I don't want create any
>   tension in the new work place, but I don't want to passive either!

Longer answer: There is nothing to be gained by emailing this person that you say started these rumors, but doing so will cause issues between you and this person in your new job.  (Especially as unless you heard directly from this person that she started the rumors you have to be relying on 3rd party reports - which you have no idea whether they are true or not)

And doubly so for wanting to commit your aspersions to a medium that will never die.

Go into your job with a clean slate.  If you feel the need to confront this person, do it in person and directly and quietly state your dislike of what happened - but only if you have 100% Incontrovertible proof that she was the source.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unring the bell of gossip about your departure. Just depart, politely. Somebody else suggested you apologize to your current manager for the gossip mill getting ahead of you. That is part of being polite, so do it if you wish.  That being said, wise managers avoid acting, or getting upset, based on gossip. There's a s**t-ton of gossip in any busy workplace, most of it is total rubbish, and experienced managers know that. So don't worry about it too much.

You've learned something about the recruiting process, though. Confidentiality is important to candidates; it's up to candidates to pick the time and place of announcing they will take another job. It's not up to the gossip mill.

Teach what you've learned to your new co-workers. Good recruiting is a team effort. And, keeping confidentiality is a vital part of recruiting. Sure, the HR person deals with the headhunters and screens resumes. The hiring manager decides who gets the offer. Other members of the team have their parts to do, even if it's just doing an interview, or keeping their mouths shut about who's interviewing.

You don't have to call anybody out personally. You can just say to the team, "let me tell you a story about a candidate I know, and how she was embarrassed by rumors."

There are other tasks and skills involved in recruiting. You might ask your new HR person to do an hour's talk on the process for your new team.